# Is there a way to subscribe to a topic without setting the type?

Tags: ros, python, topic, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to create some UI to allow users to select a topic and visualize the data published on that topic. To get started I wanted to have only one field for the topic name and connect to it with python. In theory it should be possible to receive callbacks without knowing the message type since the messages are introspectable in python using:

```
message.__slots__
message._slot_types
message.__getattribute__('x')
```

I tried to use the Subscriber class but that one enforces the use of a data class when you subscribe to a topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36855/is-there-a-way-to-subscribe-to-a-topic-without-setting-the-type?/) by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try and use the internal rostopic API directly to list topic names and detect the topic type (see the code API page for rostopic [here](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/electric/api/rostopic/html/))

The only drawback of using the API directly is that code breaking changes may be made to it in the future. If you are worried about this, you could potentially try and parse the output of the rostopic command, as this command line tool is stable.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

piyushk is correct, but according to the [wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/rostopic), "rostopic is a stable command-line tool within the ROS core toolchain. The underlying code may undergo refactoring for easier library use, but the external API is expected to be fairly stable."

Using functions like:

> get_topic_type

```
data_type = rostopic.get_topic_type('my_topic', blocking=False)[0]
if data_type:
      data_class = roslib.message.get_message_class(data_type)
      #... do fun things here
```

Now, according to [REP100](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0100.txt) roslib.message is supposed to be moved to [rosgraph](http://ros.org/doc/unstable/api/rosgraph/html/) but I can't find it there, even in fuerte.

I hope that this was really a reference to something else.. because there is sooo much code that is still using roslib.message...

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) on 2012-06-24**:
Thank you!
To get the data class you can use "rostopic.get_topic_class('topic')" directly.

**Comment by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) on 2012-06-24**:
Thank you!To get the data class you can use "rostopic.get_topic_class('topic')" directly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

import rospy
import sys

```
from importlib import import_module

class Listener(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._binary_sub = rospy.Subscriber(
            'some_topic', rospy.AnyMsg, self.topic_callback)

    def topic_callback(self, data):
        assert sys.version_info >= (2,7) #import_module's syntax needs 2.7
        connection_header =  data._connection_header['type'].split('/')
        ros_pkg = connection_header[0] + '.msg'
        msg_type = connection_header[1]
        print 'Message type detected as ' + msg_type
        msg_class = getattr(import_module(ros_pkg), msg_type)
        msg = msg_class().deserialize(data._buff)

        print data.known_field
```

Based on article http://schulz-m.github.io/2016/07/18/rospy-subscribe-to-any-msg-type/

---

Originally posted by [KindDragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/41693/kinddragon/) with karma: 11 on 2019-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For your information, there is a package in C++ that does exactly this:

https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_type_introspection

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2019-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A version using a callback to make it a drop-in replacement for a `rospy.Subscriber()`. Based on KindDragon's answer.

Usage:

```
my_subscriber = GenericMessageSubscriber('topic_name', message_callback)

def message_callback(data):
    # handle your callback exactly as you would do it with a normal Subscriber
    print(data)
```

Class:

```
class GenericMessageSubscriber(object):
def __init__(self, topic_name, callback):
    self._binary_sub = rospy.Subscriber(
        topic_name, rospy.AnyMsg, self.generic_message_callback)
    self._callback = callback

def generic_message_callback(self, data):
    assert sys.version_info >= (2,7) #import_module's syntax needs 2.7
    connection_header =  data._connection_header['type'].split('/')
    ros_pkg = connection_header[0] + '.msg'
    msg_type = connection_header[1]
    msg_class = getattr(import_module(ros_pkg), msg_type)
    msg = msg_class().deserialize(data._buff)
    self._callback(msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2020-10-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1